# Making sense of decomposeProjectionMatrix

Tags: opencv

The function decomposeProjectionMatrix() outputs a rotMatrix as well as rotMatrX, rotMatrY, and rotMatrz (as well as other quantities).

My understanding was that rotMatrix = rotMatrX * rotMatrY * rotMatrZ (with * being the matrix multiplication operator). However, the results are not the case.

Here is an example of the decomposition.

```
# Decompose rotation vector using Rodridgues decomposition.
self.rotation_matrix, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(self.rotation_vector)

print("Rotation matrix returned from Rodrigues:\n", self.rotation_matrix)

# Combine the rotation matrix and translation vector to create pose matrix.
self.pose_matrix = cv2.hconcat((self.rotation_matrix, self.translation_vector))

# Decompose pose matrix in various properties.
properties = cv2.decomposeProjectionMatrix(self.pose_matrix)
self.projection_matrix = properties[0]
self.rot_matrix = properties[1]
self.trans_vect = properties[2]
self.rot_matrix_x = properties[3]
self.rot_matrix_y = properties[4]
self.rot_matrix_z = properties[5]
self.euler_angles = properties[6]

print("xyz\n",np.matmul(self.rot_matrix_x, np.matmul(self.rot_matrix_y, self.rot_matrix_z)))
print()
print("zyx\n",np.matmul(self.rot_matrix_z, np.matmul(self.rot_matrix_y, self.rot_matrix_x)))
print()
print("yxz\n",np.matmul(self.rot_matrix_y, np.matmul(self.rot_matrix_x, self.rot_matrix_z)))
print()
print(self.rot_matrix)
```

Here is an example of actual output:

```
Rotation matrix returned from Rodrigues:
 [[-0.00353424  0.99998718  0.00362615]
 [-0.145003   -0.00410033  0.98942272]
 [ 0.9894249   0.00297105  0.14501563]]
xyz
 [[-0.00353424 -0.145003    0.9894249 ]
 [ 0.99998718 -0.00410033  0.00297105]
[ 0.00362615  0.98942272  0.14501563]]

zyx
 [[-0.00353424 -0.99899952 -0.04458098]
 [ 0.145003   -0.04462205  0.98842451]
 [-0.9894249  -0.00297105  0.14501563]]

yxz
 [[-0.0237951  -0.14450917  0.98921731]
 [ 0.99949335 -0.02436119  0.02048349]
 [ 0.02113845  0.98920353  0.14501563]]

 [[-0.00353424  0.99998718  0.00362615]
 [-0.145003   -0.00410033  0.98942272]
 [ 0.9894249   0.00297105  0.14501563]]
```

We see that xyz or zyx does not give us back the rotation matrix! zyx almost gives us the right result, but there is a negative sign error!  What is the problem!?!? Thank you!

Comment: I would have said `Rz@Rx@Ry` or `Rz@Ry@Rx` because they are quite acknowledged standards but I got for both a norm error of 0.5 which is quite confusing...

Comment: Alas, the problem with Euler angles is that there really is no standard ...